# Cannot success query in android-SQLite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm learning android studio.
As a Book Manegement App,I coded this MainActivity.kt and SimpleDatabaseHelper.kt

SimpleDatabaseHelper class in SimpleDatabaseHelper.kt

```
class SimpleDatabaseHelper (context: Context?): SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DBNAME,null, VERSION{      
    companion object{
    private const val  VERSION=1 
    private const val  DBNAME="sample.sqlite" 
    }
    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        db?.let{
            it.execSQL("CREATE TABLE books("+"isbn TEXT PRIMARY KEY,title TEXT,price INTEGER)")
            val initialBookData=listOf(
                mapOf("isbn" to "00001-0001","title" to "11111111","price" to "1234"),
                mapOf("isbn" to "00002-0002","title" to "2222222","price" to "3000"),
                mapOf("isbn" to "00003-0003","title" to "333333","price" to "3500"),
                mapOf("isbn" to "00004-0004","title" to "4444444","price" to "600"),
                mapOf("isbn" to "00005-0005","title" to "55555555","price" to "1000"),
                mapOf("isbn" to "00006-0006","title" to "66666","price" to "1111")
            )
            it.beginTransaction()
            try{
                val sql=it.compileStatement(
                    "INSERT INTO books(isbn,title,price) VALUES(?,?,?)"
                )
                initialBookData.forEach{
                    sql.bindString(1, it["isbn"] )
                    sql.bindString(2, it["title"] )
                    sql.bindString(3, it["price"])
                    sql.executeInsert()
                }
                it.setTransactionSuccessful()
            }catch(e:SQLException){
                e.printStackTrace()
            }finally {
                it.endTransaction()
            }
        }
    }
    
    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        db?.let{
            it.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS books")
            onCreate(it)
        }
    }
    
    override fun onOpen(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        super.onOpen(db)
    }
}
```

MainActivity class in MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4)
        val txtSearch = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.textSearch)
        val txtSearchTitle = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textSearchTitle)
        val txtSearchAnswer = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textSearchAnswer)
        val btnS = findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonToSearch)
        val btnD = findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonToDelete)
        val btnI = findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonToInsert)
        val helper = SimpleDatabaseHelper(this)
    
        btnI.setOnClickListener {
            helper.writableDatabase.use { db ->
                val cv = ContentValues().apply {
                    put("isbn", "new_isbn")
                    put("title", txtSearch.text.toString())
                    put("price", "10000")
                }
                db.insertWithOnConflict("books", null, cv, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
        btnD.setOnClickListener {
            helper.writableDatabase.use { db ->
                val params = arrayOf(txtSearch.text.toString())
                db.delete("books", "isbn= ?", params)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    
            }
        }
        btnS.setOnClickListener {
            val cols = arrayOf("isbn", "title", "price")
            val params = arrayOf(txtSearch.text.toString())
            helper.readableDatabase.use { db ->
                db.query(
                    "books", cols, "isbn = ?",
                    params, null, null, null, null
                ).use { cs ->
                    if (cs.moveToFirst()) {
                        txtSearchTitle.setText(cs.getString(1))
                        txtSearchTitle.setText(cs.getString(2))
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "No Book Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        helper.writableDatabase.use { db ->
            Log.d("DATABASE", "connected to SearchDatabase")
        }
    }
}
```

When searching by isbn, title and price should display from database

```
                mapOf("isbn" to "00001-0001","title" to "11111111","price" to "1234"),
                mapOf("isbn" to "00002-0002","title" to "2222222","price" to "3000"),
                mapOf("isbn" to "00003-0003","title" to "333333","price" to "3500"),
                mapOf("isbn" to "00004-0004","title" to "4444444","price" to "600"),
                mapOf("isbn" to "00005-0005","title" to "55555555","price" to "1000"),
                mapOf("isbn" to "00006-0006","title" to "66666","price" to "1111")
```

but when I searched "00001-0001", no book found.
How can I resolve this?

Checking Database Inspecter, it seems database isn't created properly.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Sorry . Implementing this codes in new project, somehow I got success.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is that you ran the App and had an issue in the onCreate method, you fixed that issue and then reran and then experienced the issue with the data/row not being found.

This would be due to the fact that when the onCreate method is called/invoked that the database has at that time been created but it has no tables other the the system tables (sqlite_master and android_metadata).

- in your case, as an error would not set the transaction as successfully, then the transaction would be rolled back, so even if the table had been created it's creation would be rolled back and thus the table would not then exist.

Any subsequent run, as the database itself exists, would not invoke the onCreate method and hence App Inspection would could appear to be " database isn't created properly.".

> Implementing this codes in new project, somehow I got success.

This would work as the intial issue has been corrected and as the database does not exist for the new project, then onCreate will be called and do what is expected.

To fix the old project,

1. uninstall the App, which will result in the database being deleted
2. rerun the App, which will install it and onCreate will be called.